# How to disable the annoying compatibility warnings in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Every time I edit a CVS or 2003-2007 Excel file it gives a warning that it will be saved in compatibility mode. I have this habit of saving every other minute via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and the window keeps popping up.

How can I disable this annoying 'Compatibility mode pop-up'?

Answer (score 3):

For Excel 2003-2007 files you can uncheck the "Check compatibility when saving this workbook" option in the dialog that pops up. This only applies to the specific workbook you're saving. But, that would be enough to get the pop up to stop showing up every time you go to save the file. You can at least work on one file in piece. I looked for this same option for .csv files but didn't find anything in the same vein.

If you're adventurous, you can try the [Disable Excel Compatibility Checker](http://www.excelguru.ca/node/105) plug-in over on Excel Guru. The author says it's pretty basic, only works with .xls files, and hasn't been tested all that thoroughly. But hey, might be worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no such checkbox and the compatibility checker does not work for Excel 2010.

Comment: @chronoz apparently i need 10 rep to post an image (if you upvote once i'll add it). I'm using Excel 2010 and the checkbox is in the bottom left right above the "Copy to New Sheet" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can work in the .xlsx format to avoid the warning message and when you're done just "Save as" in .csv or .xls format - this way you'll see the pop-up just once. Hope that helps.

Comment: Right, but I need to process the csv files with PHP, so that would not work.

Comment: Oh, I see; so you get the message every time you try to save the file in php, right?