# Can Excel be configured to not display the “Compatibility Checker” save dialog?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sas

(I already posted this question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25096950/7491). It was recommended I post it here as well. I probably should have "migrated" the question, but I'm not sure how that is done.)

The situation:

- Users have created many spreadsheets over many years, using various versions of Excel
- We are now working on a “data migration” process
- We have a utility to open and update selected parts of programmatically-identified Excel spreadsheets
- Upon saving, the “Compatibility Checker” dialog box opens up, and someone must manually select “Continue”

Given that there will be hundreds of spreadsheets to update, this is (at best) inconvenient. We searched for a way to configure Excel to not automatically show this dialog, and found this post in MS Technet. Quick summary: they spell out how to add key ShowCompatDialog in the registry for Excel, which when set to 0 should do the trick.)

We’ve done this, but—even after rebooting the workstation—behavior does not change. Any ideas? Are we missing something, or is this just an undocumented MS setting that does not work? (Apparently there’s similar kludges for Word and Power Point – anyone ever tried them?)

Any ideas on anything else that might work? We haven’t messed around with Excel versions, would this happen if we had The most recent version installed?

A final complication, the master script here is a SAS routine – and it must be, to identify the modifications required by our system.

---

Addenda, based on the comments from the SO posting. There are two SU posts related to this:

- [How to disable the annoying compatibility warnings in Excel?](https://superuser.com/q/299282/35719)
- [Turning off Excel Compatibility Checker for “Significant Loss of Functionality” errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15121982/7491)

Add-ins aren't really an option (IT is very sensitive about the boxes we'll be doing this on), and the programming options are apparently not available when scripting from SAS.

Comment: Could you link to the Technet post please?

Comment: The hyperlink didn't copy over from the original SO post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5d7ac57e-e219-42c5-8277-ced3adb1a217/how-can-i-permanently-disable-excels-compatiblity-checker?forum=excel